# line 30, in <module> writer.writerow(data) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
main_url = "https://www.datatrust.construction/news/"
```

def webscraper(url):
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
return soup

```
 with open('article.csv', 'w' , newline="") as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    headers = ["Title", "Date", "Intro"]
    writer.writerow(headers)
```

for url in main_url:

```
for item in webscraper(main_url).find_all("div", class_ = "et_pb_ajax_pagination_container"):
         data=[]
         #title
         print(item.article.h2.a.text)
         #date
         print(item.article.p.text)
         #Intro
         print(item.div.text)
         print("\n")
        
         writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to the fact that you call writer.writerow(data) in a loop outside the with statement block in which writeFile exists (writer is bound to writeFile). so after the with statement block was edited, the stream was closed.

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
main_url = "https://www.datatrust.construction/news/"

```
def webscraper(url): 
    result = requests.get(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser') 
    return soup

with open('article.csv', 'w' , newline="") as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    headers = ["Title", "Date", "Intro"]
    writer.writerow(headers)
    
    #take note of the indentation
    for url in main_url:
        for item in webscraper(main_url).find_all("div", class_ = "et_pb_ajax_pagination_container"):
             data=[]
             #title
             print(item.article.h2.a.text)
             #date
             print(item.article.p.text)
             #Intro
             print(item.div.text)
             print("\n")
            
             writer.writerow(data)
```

Next time, make sure you format your code in your questions well, and also describe your problem correctly (in title and description)